# Parse time with different formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a string that I need to convert to datetime format. The problem is that it doesn't always have the same format. Right now I'm using try, except to try all the formats that I might encounter (see code below). Is there a way to do this generically for all time formats?

```
import datetime

def get_time(start_time):    
        try:
            start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')                                    
            return start_time
        except:
            try:
                start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M:%S')                
                return start_time
            except:
                try:
                    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')                    
                    return start_time
                except:
                    print("Error could not convert datetime format")
```

Comment: use list with patterns and `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) would be very useful for a task like this - it can appropriately parse most formats.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse(start_time)
```

Alternatively, I think you have the right idea with try/except statements, however you should just place all of the formats in a list and iterate over the list with a single try-except block instead of the ugly nesting.

```
formats = ['%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M']               
def get_time(start_time):
    for formt in formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(start_time, formt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print('Could not convert datetime format')
    # or raise an error
```